# install service in windows server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008

As a Resource Kit doesn't exists for Windows Server 2008, how do you install a service? instsrv and srvany are no where to find..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The "SC" command can do everything (and more) that the old INSTSRV could do. The command-line syntax is a bit strange (with the spaces after all the equals signs), but it works fine.

SRVANY can be found around the 'net and will work in W2K8, but if you want an alternative that can be legally re-distributed, look at the [Non-Sucking Service Manager](http://iain.cx/src/nssm/).

Comment: The history of the NSSM tool -> http://stuff.iain.cx/2010/04/21/nssm-2-3/#more-221

Answer (score 1):

Additional details to what @Evan Anderson provided.

On a 64 bit version of Windows Server 2008 you need to use 'nssm.exe' file found in the 'win64' folder.

- Then create a batch/cmd file with the following syntax:
- c:\path_to_nssm_exe\nssm.exe install the_service_name "c:\the_application_path\application.exe"
- Then right-click on the batch/cmd file and 'Run as Administrator'

Comment: Very useful tip, neither nssm exe's worked for me, creating the batch file did something to enabled it. I'd added nssm to my path etc.